# cosign-api add reason to SOAP request

Tags: cosign-api

I am trying to add a reason to the soap request for a COSign SOAP signing.

Can anyone provide me with a VB or C# example of how to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Below for anyone with the same problem

```
Dim Configs(1) As DSSSoapClient.ConfValueType
    Dim Config As New DSSSoapClient.ConfValueType() With { _
            .ConfValueID = DSSSoapClient.ConfIDEnum.Reason, _
            .Item = "Hierdie is die Rede vir al my harseer"
        }
    Configs(1) = Config


    ' Build complete request object
    Dim signRequest As New DSSSoapClient.SignRequest() With { _
        .InputDocuments = New DSSSoapClient.RequestBaseTypeInputDocuments() With { _
            .Items = New DSSSoapClient.DocumentType() {document} _
        }, _
        .OptionalInputs = New DSSSoapClient.RequestBaseTypeOptionalInputs() With { _
            .SignatureType = signatureType, _
            .ClaimedIdentity = claimedIdentity, _
            .SAPISigFieldSettings = sigFieldSettings, _
            .ReturnPDFTailOnly = True, _
            .ConfigurationValues = Configs, _
            .ReturnPDFTailOnlySpecified = True _
        } _
    }
```